# How to add Edit/Done button to individual UIViewControllers embedded in the same UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm currently working on an app that contains a table view controller embedded in a navigation view controller which, after the user selects a cell from the table, or "adds" a new cell, multiple view controllers embedded in a UITabBarController, are populated appropriately and made able to edit.

I'm trying to add an Edit/Done button, which I've done successfully, however, the results are not quite as desired. You see, I'm attempting to make the Edit/Done button visible in only 3 of the 4 embedded view controllers.

One thing I noticed when forming the segue between the add cell (+) button and the next view is that the segue must connect to the UITabBarController, rather than any of the individual UIViewControllers embedded in said tab bar controller. This led me to try adding the necessary Edit/Done button code in the tab bar controller code, however, the button appears for all tabs (which is not what I'm looking for).

I'd like to control the behavior of said Edit/Done button on an individual basis--that is, on a tab-by-tab basis. This way, I'd be able to not only change the effect of the edit button for the specific situation, but the appearance of the button would be more "discretionary" to begin with.

The following code is in my tab bar controller class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
}

override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if(editing){

    }else{

    }
}
```

BTW: I'm developing using Swift in Xcode 6.2

Thanks.

Comment: This is weird.  Are you saying the tabBarController is in a navigation controller?  usually its the other way around.  Each tab is a a navigation controller that embeds all of the views that are part of that tab; one navigation controller per tab.

Comment: If each of your ViewController is embedded in UINavigationController before it is embedded in UITabBarController. Then, your task is not a problem

Comment: Only the initial table view controller is actually embedded in a navigation controller, however, as a byproduct of forming a segue from the table view controller to the tab bar controller, a navigation bar is "brought along." Are you suggesting that it's OK to have multiple view controllers embedded in their own navigation controllers, even if there is a segue leading to said view controllers from a previous embedded view controller?